# Laravel's Illuminate paginator can't find query string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, illuminate-container, laravel-pagination

I'm working on a old PHP project, that is running in legacy SQL query, which is good but I like to use query builders like Laravel Illuminate SQL package!

So i have added all required package dependencies to run Illuminate SQL, and this query builder seems to work fine with pagination!

```
$users = Capsule::table('users')->paginate(1)->toArray();
```

But, the paginator seems not to be able to listen the query string! For example, by running the above code it would give some properties like, next_page , previous_page etc...

[image]

And when I try to pass the query string in the URL it can't fetch the data from query string(From the GET request)!

Visiting this page `http://app.app/?page=2` would give the same result set.

How i should configure the Illuminate sql package so it can also listen to the query strings?

**EDIT**

Also, i've tried to use the `illuminate/http` package, but the `$request->all()` method always returns an empty array! Here is the code:

```
<?php
  require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
  use \Illuminate\Http\Request;

  $req = new Request();

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($req->all());
  echo '</pre>';
```

It returns empty input data array,
[image]

What i am missing to use the http package, any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set a page resolver:

```
\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::currentPageResolver(function ($pageName = 'page') {
    return (int) ($_GET[$pageName] ?? 1);
});
```

Laravel uses [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0d94dfee3f745d92a62de453a45c073dee6f0536/src/Illuminate/Pagination/PaginationServiceProvider.php#L40) resolver.

Comment: Any tips on how I should go further with using the `\Illuminate\Http` package?

Comment: Do you mean to replace `$_GET` with a `Request` instance?

Comment: Not exactly that, i'm trying to use the Request instance to handle all the requests from the PHP application. I've edited the question few hours ago, that shows how i've implemented the request package inside the PHP project, but getting an empty array response.

Comment: Use `$req = Request::createFromGlobals();`.

Comment: Is all the `Illuminate\*` packages provides the `createFromGlobals()` method?

Comment: `createFromGlobals()` is only a method of the `Request` class.

Comment: You helped a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to notice, that paginator won't use other parameters for query string - it just uses `page` parameter to get valid results page. But for example if you use:

```
http://app.app/?page=2&price=2
```

it won't take from database results with price = 2 - it's your job to do this.

However the 2nd thing are urls generated by paginator.

If you do it like this:

```
$users = Capsule::table('users')->paginate(1);
```

You can also use in next line

```
$users->appends(request()->except('page'));
```

This will add all other parameters from query string (except page) to urls, so `first_page_url` will then contain all other parameters from request.

You can also wrap it using fluent syntax like this:

```
$users = Capsule::table('users')->paginate(1)->appends(request()->except('page'));
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to fetch the query string in the controller to pass the get parameter to 
  paginate.
- You can use the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class to receive and use the HTTP payload.

**Your controller file:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class YourControllerClassName{
    public function someFunction(Request $request){
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($request->all());
         print_r($request->input('page'));
         $users = Capsule::table('users')->paginate($request->input('page'))->toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this too; but for some reason the request->all returns empty array all the time

Comment: @rakibtg Why do you `autoload `on your own? Also, the reason you are getting an empty array is because you are creating an object of `Request` on your own. Make a controller file in `App\http\controllers`. Make a route in `routes/web.php`.  Copy the above code and paste it in your controller. Save it and make a request from browser. You should see that it works.

Comment: I am trying to use this packages outside of the laravel framework, that's why i was instantiating the Request.

Comment: @rakibtg why so? If you want to use these packages outside of Laravel, then you don't need Laravel. You can have `composer.json` file in your project, mention the packages you want to have in `require` field and do a `composer install` and `composer dump-autoload` and you are ready to go.

Comment: can you give an example composer.json file, would be really helpful